# Moving a web application from Jrun to Tomcat server

Tags: apache, tomcat, web-applications, jrun

I have a web application running on jrun server. I have to move it to tomcat server. What could the possible changes be ?

Answer (score 0):

There are many since you may also need to contend with different Java versions and Servlet API versions but the primary task is simply to convert your Jrun context description files into Tomcat ones (either in server.xml or in seperate files per the [Tomcat deployment documentation](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.0-doc/appdev/deployment.html)).

Tomcat also comes with some built-in web applications (eg, host-manager) for managing your deployments via a web interface but for a simple setup that might be overkill.

It couldn't hurt to specify a little more about the application you're migrating. Given the initial choice of JRun I suspect you're migrating a Coldfusion site and you may find advice more directly relevant to your situation by clarifying that up front if true.

You'll also need to change from the apache-jrun connector to a tomcat AJP or mod_proxy connection method. A few lines like below in your http.conf should be sufficient depending on your situation:

```
# Proxy CFML files to Tomcat/Jetty
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} /[^/:]+\.cfml*($|/)
RewriteRule (.*) ajp://%{HTTP_HOST}:8009$1 [P,L]
```